# Passing python list of dates to sql query where clause

Tags: python, sql, timestamp

I have a date column in the data frame which I convert to a list of dates

```
begdtlist = df["BEG_DT"].tolist()
```

`print(begdtlist)` returns following.

```
Timestamp('2018-04-29 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-04-22 00:00:00'), 
Timestamp('2018-04-22 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-04-29 00:00:00'), 
Timestamp('2018-04-29 00:00:00').
```

Date is getting type casted to Timestamp.

I pass this list to an SQL query as below

```
sql = ("select  calndr_dt,wk_of_mnth from DatabaseName where calndr_dt = cast {} as date").format(repr(begdtlist).replace('[','(').replace(']',')'))
```

However my sql is generated in the below format which is causing the query to fail.

```
"select  calndr_dt,wk_of_mnth from DatabaseName where calndr_dt = cast 
(Timestamp('2018-04-29 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-04-22 00:00:00'), 
Timestamp('2018-04-22 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-04-29 00:00:00'), 
Timestamp('2018-04-29 00:00:00')) as date"
```

I am not sure why it is coming as a Timestamp. I just need the date portion in quotes. Any guidance in accomplishing this would be appreciated.

Comment: Please fix your indentation so that we can see the code formatted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are yousing `repr()` to transform an object into a string. This method is not intended for the use case you apply it to; it gives information on the internal representation of the underlying object.

What you really want to do is to *format* your timestamp to make it a string that suits your needs. Just as regular python `Datetime` objects, `pandas`' `Timestamp` objects also have a method called `strftime()` that is used for string formatting.

```
# This part is just to create a MWE; it mimics your dataframe that we
# do not have at hand here.
df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'BEG_DT': [
        pandas.Timestamp('2018-04-29'),
        pandas.Timestamp('2019-04-22')]
    })

# This is what you did
begdtlist = df['BEG_DT'].tolist()
print(begdtlist)

# This is how you can format the date according to your needs
for dt in begdtlist:
    print(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

This generates the following output:

```
[Timestamp('2018-04-29 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-04-22 00:00:00')]
2018-04-29
2019-04-22
```

You see that the formatting has created the date strings you need for your SQL query generation in lines 2 and 3. You can read up on [formatting options in the official python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

By the way, it is totally fine that `pandas` transforms your dates into its own `Timestamp` objects, because they require interfaces for `DataFrame` interaction and aggregation, etc. that are not present in regular python `Date` or `Datetime` objects.

Still, you *cannot* use the list in your SQL query, because it will generate invalid syntax:

```
SELECT calndr_dt, wk_of_mnth
FROM databasename
WHERE calendr_dt = CAST 2018-04-29, 2018-04-22 AS DATE
                                  ^
                    this will be your syntax error
```

Your approach is flawed in several ways:

1. You are trying to plug in a list into a single `CAST` call, which will fail
2. You are testing equality of a column against an array, which will fail

Thus, you may also want to read up on SQL syntax and generate an example query *before* trying to plug in values via python.

It *may* look like this (**untested - use with caution**):

```
sql = '''
    SELECT calndr_dt, wk_of_mnth
    FROM databasename
    WHERE calendr_dt IN [{:s}]
'''.format(', '.join(
    [
        '\'{:s}\'::DATE'.format(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        for dt in begdtlist
    ]
))
```

Which results in:

```
SELECT calndr_dt, wk_of_mnth
FROM databasename
WHERE calendr_dt IN ['2018-04-29'::DATE, '2019-04-22'::DATE]
```

Comment: With some minor modifications, I have been able to make it working. Thank you very much for your help.